# The text within tags$div does not wrap automatically when the page size changes

Tags: r, shiny, tags

Using tags$div, I am trying to include a short note (citation) into my shiny app. The note does not wrap when the page size changes. 
Here is the code:

```
tags$div(
            id = "cite",
            '2010 Data: 2010 U.S. Census Bureau (2011). Census Summary File 1 & Investigative Reporters and Editors, Inc. Census.Ire.org Online Database.',
            style = "color: black; font-size: 12px ; width: 220px;
            white-space: nowrap; overflow: visible"
          ),
```

I changed the visible option to auto, scroll but the problem exist. 
Best,
Nader
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: visible`?

Since your `div` also have a fixed width, it is never affected by the page size. You have to use `%` instead of `px`. I attached a border, so you can now. If you want to break the text based on a specific width, use a bootstrap class like `"col-sm-4"` or use media queries.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(

    uiOutput("static"),
    uiOutput("dynamic")


)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$dynamic <- renderUI({
        tags$div(
            id = "cite",
            '2010 Data: 2010 U.S. Census Bureau (2011). Census Summary File 1 & Investigative Reporters and Editors, Inc. Census.Ire.org Online Database.',
            style = "color: black; font-size: 12px ; width: 25%;
            overflow-wrap: break-word; border:1px solid red;"
        )
    })

    output$static <- renderUI({
        tags$div(
            id = "cite2",
            '2010 Data: 2010 U.S. Census Bureau (2011). Census Summary File 1 & Investigative Reporters and Editors, Inc. Census.Ire.org Online Database.',
            style = "color: black; font-size: 12px ; width: 220px;
            white-space: nowrap; overflow: visible; border:1px solid red;"
        )
    })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks DSGym. You are right: width must be in percentage. However, "white-space: pre-line" does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
tags$div(
      id = "cite",
      '2010 Data: 2010 U.S. Census Bureau (2011). Census Summary File 1 & Investigative Reporters and Editors, Inc. Census.Ire.org Online Database.',
      style = "color: black; font-size: 12px ; width: 100%;
   white-space: pre-line"
    ),
```

[image]